# Maximum length of RSS description item

Tags: rss

Is there a length limit or maximum size for description tag inside an RSS item?

Also, does this tag accommodate HTML tags?

I will be generating both the `<description>` and `<content:encoded>` from the same source HTML and also wanted to know if the `<description>` tag accommodates HTML.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I know there are not a  length limit.
[2](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html)

> In [RSS 0.91](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html), various elements are restricted to 500 or 100 characters. There can be no more than 15 < item >s in a 0.91 < channel >. There are no string-length or XML-level limits in RSS 0.92 and greater. Processors may impose their own limits, and generators may have preferences that say no more than a certain number of < item >s can appear in a channel, or that strings are limited in length.
>
> [Rss 2.0](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile)
>
> For all elements defined in the RSS specification that enclose
> character data, the text should be interpreted as plain text with the
> exception of an item's description element, which must be suitable for
> presentation as HTML. All of these elements must not contain child
> elements.
>
> **There's no limit on the length of character data that can be contained in an RSS element.**

So do you want to cut text somewhere and add ...?
In this case just use substr.

```
$description = substr($description, 0, 250)."...";
```

Replace 250 by the size you want.

Comment: This would break the text mid word if the 250 character boundary was in the middle of a word. So you would end up with something like ...`char...`.

Comment: So there is no standard? Anybody know what's a good policy? @Treffynnon - I don't care so much as to where it breaks since it seems that most modern readers will use `<content:encoded>` anyway...

Comment: Treffynoon : yes , it cuts sometimes in the middle of the word.

Comment: `mb_substr` works in a safer way, avoiding truncate html codes, also you can use CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis`

Answer (score 0):

#### RSS 2.00 Limits

RSS 1.00 only [has a working version that was never officially published](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss1.html).  Since it is completely different from 2.00, 0.92, and 0.91, it is largely just not implemented and skipped over.

*No limits in RSS 2.00!*  To quote the documentation...

> In RSS 0.91, various elements are restricted to 500 or 100 characters. There can be no more than 15  in a 0.91 . There are no string-length or XML-level limits in RSS 0.92 and greater. (Source: [**RSS 2.0 Specification**](https://www.rssboard.org/rss-2-0).)

#### RSS 0.92 Limits

*No limits!*  To quote the documentation...

> In RSS 0.91 various elements are restricted to 500 or 100 characters. There can be no more than 15  in a 0.91 .
>
> There are no string-length or XML-level limits in RSS 0.92. (Source: [**RSS 0.92 Specification**](https://www.rssboard.org/rss-0-9-2))

#### RSS 0.91 Limits

***Elements Limited to An Enum:***

- `<language>` — `channel` Sub-element; may only be "en", "en-UK", "en-UK", etc.
- `<pubDate>` — `channel` Sub-element; may only be of the Date and Time Specification of RFC 822
- `<lastBuildDate>` — `channel` Sub-element; may only be of the Date and Time Specification of RFC 822
- `<width>` — `image` Sub-element; may only be an integer from 1 to 144.
- `<height>` — `image` Sub-element; may only be an integer from 1 to 400.
- `<name>` — `textInput` Sub-element; may only be an integer from 1 to 20.

***Elements Limited to 100 Characters***

- `<title>` — `channel` Sub-element; `item` Sub-element; `image` Sub-element; `textInput` Sub-element
- `<copyright>` — `channel` Sub-element
- `<managingEditor>` — `channel` Sub-element
- `<webMaster>` — `channel` Sub-element

***Elements Limited to 500 Characters***

- `<link>` — `channel` Sub-elements
- `<description>` — `channel` Sub-element; `item` Sub-element; `textInput` Sub-element
- `<rating>` — `channel` Sub-element
- `<docs>` — `channel` Sub-element
- `<url>` — `image` Sub-element
- `<link>` — `item` Sub-element; `image` Sub-element; `textInput` Sub-element

(Source: [**RSS 0.91 Specification**](https://www.rssboard.org/rss-0-9-1-netscape).)