# size of an RSS item body

Tags: rss, rss-reader

I want to store the items of an RSS feed in a database. I created a table 'items' where, among other fields (author, guid, ...), I have a field for the body. How big should that be? Is there a limitation on the size of the body of an rss item? If not, what's the average of this size?

EDIT: as pointed out by random, [Maximum length of RSS description item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8710676/825190) already answers my first two questions. The last one remains open: I still wonder if anyone has run tests on the average of the content of the description tag in a rss feed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RSS - Item description length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710676/rss-item-description-length)

Comment: @random: thanks! that answer my first two questions, but not the last one.